# Reading a Multigraph in NetworkX from gml file

Tags: python, networkx

I am attempting to read a gml file into a multigraph object; however, I am receiving the following error:

```
NetworkXError: edge #1 (0--3) is duplicated
```

In the gml file the the edge is duplicated:

```
  edge [
    source 0
    target 3
    LinkLabel "Green"
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 3
    LinkLabel "Brown"
  ]
```

As I understand it, the read_gml function should return a multigraph when the input is a multigraph.  What am I missing?

Comment: It would be nice if you are able to show a minimum gml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your gml file probably lacks of `multigraph 1` below `graph [`. Here is a MWE.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_gml('test.gml')

print(type(G))              # <class 'networkx.classes.multigraph.MultiGraph'>
print(G.edges(data=True))   # [(0, 3, {u'LinkLabel': u'Green'}), (0, 3, {u'LinkLabel': u'Brown'})]
```

The content of `test.gml`,

```
graph [
  multigraph 1
  node [
    id 0
    label 0
  ]
  node [
    id 3
    label 3
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 3
    LinkLabel "Green"
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 3
    LinkLabel "Brown"
  ]
]
```